# dynamic string obtained from php

Tags: php

I have a text which is dynamically fetched and has several lines. I want to fetch the last line of the text. I thought of using substr() but couldn't as I would know the string only at run time. I'm using php. Please help me on doing this.

Comment: `explode` the string using newline character. Last item in the array is your last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$yourstring = explode("\r\n",$yourstring);
$lastLine = $yourstring[(count($yourstring)-1)];
```

Please use the double quote with "\r\n": the single quote WON'T work.

Answer to the comment:

Then are you sure that you need to separate the break lines?

Check this piece of code:

```
$yourstring = "cicco
                    caio";
$yourstring = explode("\r\n",$yourstring);
$lastLine = $yourstring[(count($yourstring)-1)];
echo $lastLine;
```

If you want to test it online, test it here:

http://writecodeonline.com/php/

It actually works for me and echoes "caio".

Can you please provide us the string you need to elaborate? maybe we're not talking about new lines? :)

Comment: Check the answer again, maybe it's not about new lines!

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into parts where delimiter is the new line character, most likely "\r\n" or just "\n". Check which one fits. Then use the php function [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and take the last one with [end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php). So

```
echo end(explode("\r\n", $your_string));
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your newline character, you might need to change "\n"

```
$array = explode("\n", $string);
echo end($array);
```

Comment: @user2509780 you might need to change the "\n" to suit your line breaks in your string